# Is there an official reason for the change in spelling of Roy's surname?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner, do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

In *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?* Roy’s surname is spelt Baty. In *Blade Runner* the spelling is Batty. I’ve found a lot of sites that simply note the difference, but none of them give a reason for it. I’m guessing it’s most likely one of the following:

- It’s a subtle way of noting that film Roy is quite different from book Roy (perhaps similar to *Stargate*’s O’Neil vs O’Neill).
- To make it match the word ‘batty’ (either as a pronunciation aid or a meaningful name).
- It was a typo that stuck.

Has there been an official explanation given for the change?